# Sending input parameters to AWS Lambda function from Unity

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, aws-lambda

I'm learning AWS Lambda with C#. My function looks sort of like this:

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace Function_Redeem
{
    public class Function
    {
        public FunctionOutput FunctionHandler(FunctionInput input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            // do work with input
            // return FunctionOutput
        }

        public class FunctionInput
        {
            public string someData { get; set; }
        }

        public class FunctionOutput
        {
            public string someAnswer { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine when using the Test button in AWS, as well as the test feature in Visual Studio.

Now, I'm trying to call this from Unity.

So first, I added an API Gateway trigger, and left the defaults:

```
API endpoint: [the url]
API type: HTTP
Authorization: NONE
Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS): No
Enable detailed metrics: No
Method: ANY
Resource path: /FunctionName
Stage: default
```

Then in Unity,

```
private static IEnumerator TestFunction(string uri, string data)
{
    UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Put(uri, data);
    yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
    if (webRequest.isNetworkError)
        Debug.LogError("Network error: " + webRequest.error);
    else
        Debug.Log(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
}
```

I call it, with `data` being

```
{"someData":"Hello"}
```

The function call *works*, I know that it is reaching my function, but the input data (i.e. the `someData` field) is null. It seems like it's not parsing the data I'm sending so `FunctionInput` defaults to null `someData`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using API Gateway as a trigger to your lambda function, accept [APIGatewayProxyRequest](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayProxyRequest.cs) as input parameter to your handler(instead of FunctionInput). The field [Body](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/00009c7d4fb4fb406c355a99d11d142718ba4374/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayProxyRequest.cs#L101) would have your serialized payload `{"someData":"Hello"}`

```
public class Function
{
    public FunctionOutput FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
    {    var requestBody =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FunctionInput>(request.Body);
        // do work with input
        // return FunctionOutput
    }

    public class FunctionInput
    {
        public string someData { get; set; }
    }

    public class FunctionOutput
    {
        public string someAnswer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}